# How to force users to log in with OAuth

Tags: 7, users, authentication-authorization

My site forces users to log in with a specific OAuth provider for some reasons. Users should not be able to log in using their username and password pairs. Only the site managers can have accounts independent of OAuth.

When first creating an account with OAuth, the 'pass' field is set to an empty string ''. My first question is whether it is the right and most secure way to prevent logging in using password.

The second question is about requesting new password via email. I implemented hook_menu_alter to customize `user` and `user/login` and to unset `user/password`. Now users cannot access `user/password`, I wonder if there is a bypass for it. This question is less important since almost all users would never bother with or even know the possibility of requesting new password.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you disable email notification of new accounts, the OpenID module will set a random password when users register. See [openid_form_user_register_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21openid%21openid.module/function/openid_form_user_register_form_alter/7). If that is not what you want, you use `hook_form_alter()` to do the same thing under your desired conditions.
2. If you want to intercept `user_pass_reset()` so it cannot reset passwords, try using `hook_form_alter()` to [add a form validation function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#validate).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to disable Drupal's own login mechanism on Drupal 6 when I wanted to force users to log in through the [Connector](http://drupal.org/project/connector) module instead: https://github.com/voxpelli/drupal-disabledefaultlogin

Never got around to release it on Drupal.org though and I'm not actively developing it anymore - but feel free to be inspired by it.